# Regex for testing that a docker image name is prefixed with a registry?

Tags: java, regex, docker, docker-registry

I'm looking for a regex that will test whether a docker image is prefixed with a registry.

Here are what it should match:

```
docker.io/library/busybox
docker.io/library/busybox:latest
docker.io/busybox
```

and what it shouldn't:

```
busybox
busybox:latest
library/busybox
library/busybox:latest
```

Comment: So you require that a `/` appears before a `:`? Or no `:` at all?

Comment: To see if a pattern is "reasonable" we need a set of its requirements. What are they?

Comment: Should it match `docker.io/library/busybox` (which in practice is identical to `busybox:latest`)?  What problems are you having with the regex in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^/]+` instead of `.*` as `*` means 0 or more whereas `+` means 1 or more repetition

And `[^/]` means any character which is not a slash.

Also why do you need the parenthesis for? These are useful to extract groups when it matches. If you only need a boolean result (match or not) you could drop them from the expression.

You edited the question so here is my edited answer:

```regex
[^/]+\.[^/.]+/([^/.]+/)?[^/.]+(:.+)?
```

Explanation:

- `[^/]`: any character not a slash
- `[^/]+`: any string not containing a slash
- `\.`: a dot (escape do not mean any character)
- `[^/.]+`: any string not containing a slash nor a dot
- `[^/]+\.[^/.]+/`: any string separated by a dot and ending with a slash (typically docker.io).
- `()?` means this could occur 0 or 1 time (optional)
- `(:.+)?`: an optional string consisting of a colon followed by any string but not empty.

Comment: Thanks, can you break this down for me?